# How to store html for use in rails form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a page with

`<p class = 'new-question'> Placeholder </p>`

I have a form on the same page

```
<%= form_for(:question, url: question_path(Question.find_by(content:))) %>
```

I want the value of `:content` to be whatever the text of the `<p>` class is, ie in this case it should be `Placeholder`, I can't just put `content: "Placeholder"` because the text will be changed by a js script. How should I do this?

Comment: ist for update a question ? Also, as i know you can't do it like that. if u want to redirect just make it in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ruby dynamically in the web page like that. `question_path(Question.find_by(content: "whatever"))` only resolves once, when the page loads, and just gives you a url that plops into the form.

The right way to do this is to dynamically change the url for the form directly with JS. If you only want to figure out the url based on the content/respective content, then you have two options:

- Load all the Questions at once so that they're available to your JS on page load. Once the JS has the content, it can look through those Questions to find the appropriate url (where you'll also need to figure out how the routes are arranged--it's usually something simple like `/questions/1/create`.
- If you're willing to make additional requests, then you can more sensibly use AJAX calls to ping your DB every time the content changes and let Rails tell you (through the AJAX) exactly what url to replace with.